# how to use reduce with dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, reduce

I have some problem understanding how to use reduce with dictionaries in python. For example I have the following dictionary.

`{1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 2}`

and I am trying to calculate the following:

```
s = 0
for i in h:
    s += h[i] * (h[i] - 1)
```

This works as expected (I get: `8`), but I my attempt to convert it to reduce paradigm fails:
`reduce(lambda x, y: x + y * (y - 1), h)`, but I am getting the wrong answer.

I assume this is because I am using keys, not values. How can I convert my code to reduce properly?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to iterate over the dictionary while reducing it with an initial value of zero.

Note, iterating over a dictionary, actually iterates over the keys so you need to index the dictionary to get the value

```
reduce(lambda x, key:x + h[key] * (h[key] - 1), h, 0)
```

Alternatively, as you are only interested in the values of the dictionary, caring least about the key, just iterate on the values of the dictionary

### Python 2.X

```
reduce(lambda x, value:x + value * (value - 1), h.itervalues(), 0)
```

### Python 3.X

```
reduce(lambda x, value:x + value * (value - 1), h.values(), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. Just a follow up: what if I will need to use keys in values in my lambda function?

Comment: @SalvadorDali: In that case, iterate over the items in the dictionary.

Comment: @SalvadorDali if you need the keys you can initialise the lambda to the same type as the mapped value (integer here) by passing it as a third argument to `reduce`, as this avoids the case where both `x` and `value` are simultaneously keys: `reduce(lambda x, value: x+h[value] * (h[value] - 1), 0)` works, and in this case, `value` is always a key, and `x` is always the accumulated sum.

Answer (score 1):

reduce function requires an iterable object. You can get an iterable object using the items or values function of the dictionary. You can pass the third parameter of reduce function which specifies what initial value you want to set

Below is an example of a dictionary using the items function. Below function change key with value vice versa

```
def merge_dict(a, b): #initial value of a is set to {}, b will get every item of dict as tuple
    key, value = b
    a[value] = a.get(value, []) + [key]
    return a

print(reduce(merge_dict, {'1': 'a', '2': 'a'}.items(), {}))
```

Ans: {'a': ['1', '2']}